# RESTful nested controller in has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a `User` that has_one `ContactInfo`.

An unrestful way to edit the contact_info would be to do this all through a single controller with a route of:

```
myapp.com/users/15/edit_contact_info
```

A more restful way would be to use two controllers, and route it like this:

```
myapp.com/users/15/contact_infos/23/edit
```

However, I don't like this, as the route includes the contact_info_id, which isn't really necessary for identifying the correct contact_info to update. Additionally, the contact_info_id is a confusing number for a user to see. (They may know their own user id, but the contact_info_id will seem like an arbitrary number).

Is there any way to RESTfully route like below:

```
myapp.com/users/15/contact_infos/edit
```

or something similar? Is this a bad idea?

Comment: show your routes file.

Comment: Good point!, I was nesting it as a plural resource as `resources :contact_infos` but changed it to `resource :contact_info` and now it looks like I want. If you post an answer for me, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :users do
  get "contact_info/edit" => 'users#edit_contact_info'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd used a plural route, instead of a singular route. With the singular route, I get `myapp.com/users/15/contact_info/edit`.

Had:

```
resources :users do
    resources :contact_infos
end
```

Changed to

```
resources :users do
    resource :contact_info
end
```